# Plotting data and polynomial equation when x-values have been transformed

Tags: data-visualization, data-transformation, back-transformation

I hope I can make my question clear, if not I will be happy to clarify.

I want to present a simple regression plot with the polynomial equation line linked to it. Those data have been tested in a model for which linear and quadratic effects were significant. The x-values are values of distance that were overdispersed and I have used a natural logarithm transformation of them in the model.

Log values aren't really meaningful. Thus, I plotted the untransformed values on a log axis:

```
plot((Total$Rayon+.001), Total$abs_d, xlab = "Radius + 0.001 (m)", 
     ylab = "Standardized difference of means (d)", las = 1, log = "x", xaxt="n")

labels <- c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100)
axis(1, at=c(0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100), labels=labels)
```

So far, so good. Here is the question: If I want to add a polynomial equation line to this plot, do I need to perform a back-transformation with the y values ?

With a plot presenting the log x-values, here is how I added the equation line:

```
x <- seq(-7, 5, 0.1)
#equation parameters obtained from the model
equa <- -0.0228*x^2 + -0.1440*x + 1.2519
lines(x, equa)
```

Comment: Log values may be even more meaningful than linear values: [Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/a-natural-log/). What is your polynomial plot intended to show? A fitted curve?

Comment: Interesting article.
The polynomial is simply for showing the model result. A fitted curve that whow the relation between x and y...

Comment: x and y should be of course on the same scale in the scatterplot as in the fitted curve. How did you calculate the coefficients? You could do it with ```lm```, see [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-basic-polynomial-regression/). I think that your second code chunk already refers to log(x), since only log(radius) can be negative.

Comment: I didn't mentionned it, but the coefficients were calculated from a meta-analysis model using function `rma` of package `Metafor`. I'm not sure I understand the second part of your comment...

Comment: ```x <- seq(-7, 5, 0.1)``` veut dire qu' il y a des ```x``` négatifs. Aussi, l'abscisse est étiquée par rayon+0.001. Il n'y a pas des rayons négatifs. Mais pour les rayons $<0,999=1-0,001$, leur logarithme sera négatif. Donc j'ai pensé que votre courbe est déjà pour les log-valeurs.

Comment: Pourriez-vous ajouter la commande de ```rma``` pour obtenir les paramètres, s.v.p.?

Comment: Merci pour le français ! 
I've taken the values from a more complex model, with other moderators:
`resMod <- rma(Total$abs_d, Total$vd, mods = ~ Total$log_rayon + Total$log_rayon2 + Total$AssT + Total$AssT2 + Total$ES +Total$log_rayon*Total$AssT2, method = "REML", data = Total)`

Comment: So apparently you have already calculated the parameters for log(x). Then you're done. But it might not look right: You may want to write the equation down with the other parameters (due to ```AssT2```) as well. Then fix ```AssT2``` and the interaction to some value. Now calculate predicted values with these variables fixed and plot them instead of ```Total$abs_d```. Or do a 3D-scatterplot with Radius and AssT2 or remove the other variable and the interaction from the model fit. Then your curve and the scatterplot will match better.